# Simple array copying issue

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make an array of 10 numbers then copy that array into a new array without the duplicates. I got it to the point where it will weed out dups but for some reason after I determine that a number is not already in the new array it wont let me put it in there. This is what I have so far. Thanks.

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class PrintingDistinctNumbers
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int[] array=new int[10];
     int[] array2=new int[10];
     int num1;
     int count = 0;
     boolean results;
     //let the user input 10 numbers
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
     {
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("please enter 10 numbers");
       num1=input.nextInt();
       array[i]=num1;
     }

     for (int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
     {
       results=search(array2 ,array[j],count);
       if(results=false);
       { 
         array[j]=array2[count];
         count++;
         break;
       }

     }
     // just a test to make sure the numbers copied over to the new array 
     System.out.println(array2[0]);
   }



   //search the second array to see if the int is allready in it 
   public static boolean search(int[] array2,int value,int count2)
   {
     //create variables
     boolean found;
     //set the variables
     found= false;
     //search the array
     for(int index=0;index<count2;index++)
     {
       if(array2[index]==value)
       {
         found=true;
         break;
       }
     }
     return found; 


   }

 }
```

Comment: I also tried moving the count declaration inside the loop that calls the search method but I am still getting the default 0 for every element in array2

Answer (score 4):

Without looking at the rest of your logic, this

```
 if(results=false);
```

doesn't look right

1. is that a typo ? You need `if (results == false)`, or more concisely, `if (!results)`
2. note the trailing semicolon, which means the following block will execute regardless of what your `if` clause evaluates to. The `;` is creating an empty block, which is entierely valid.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I didn't notice that but I'm still getting a print of 0 when I try and print out any element of array2 after entering my integers , even after the fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs:

1. The `break;` statement in the if block should not be there: That would break you out of the loop, but you need the loop to keep iterating over the array until all the elements have been copied.
2. The test is *assigning* false to result, not comparing it, so change to `if (!result)`

---

There are a few style issues too:

1. Your search method is waaaay to long; you don't need the `found` variable
2. Name your parameters with what makes sense within the method: you have `array2` when there's no `array` or `array1` in scope. Same for `count2`
3. Prefer `i` to `index` for the loop var - it's just less to type and less to read

This is more like what it should look like:

```
public static boolean search(int[] array, int value, int count) {
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (array[i] == value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
```

}

In your main method, why do you have one loop with `i` and the next with `j`? Make them both `i` - the loop variable only has scope within the loop, so there's no clash.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `if (results=false)` already mentioned by Brian Agnew, I see this:

```
  array[j]=array2[count];
```

You overwrite the values in the array, in which you stored your input with the values of an uninitialized second array. You probably meant to do

```
  array2[count] = array[j];
```

here.